# IEnumerable<string> array filtering

Tags: c#

Consider input data (on stdin) which contains information about which versions of the various libraries are being used by the current release of each product of the company:

```
Mail Server, Authentication Library, v6
Video Call Server, Authentication Library, v7
Mail Server, Data Storage Library, v10
Chat Server, Data Storage Library, v11
Mail Server, Search Library, v6
Chat Server, Authentication Library, v8
Chat Server, Presence Library, v2
Video Call Server, Data Storage Library, v11
Video Call Server, Video Compression Library, v3
```

Each line of the input consists of 3 comma-separated fields.
The first field is a product name,
the second field is a library name, and
the third field is the library version number used by that product.

**The example given above indicates that the Mail Server, uses version v6 of the Authentication Library, and the Video Call Server uses version v7 of the Authentication Library, and the Mail Server also uses version v10 of the Data Storage Library, and so on. For the purposes of this program, assume that all version numbers are of the form v where represents one or more decimal digits.**

```
public static List<String> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            /*                  
             * Here I have to process `array` as indicated
             * in the question. At the end, I need to return a List containing
             * the appropriate values                
             */
            List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
            return retVal;
        }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                String line;
                var inputLines = new List<String>();
                while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (line != "")
                        inputLines.Add(line);
                }
                var retVal = processData(inputLines);
                foreach (var res in retVal)
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Modify it so that, it processes the input data, figures out which is the latest version number of each library, and then prints the names of products which are using an outdated version (i.e. a version that is not the latest version) of at least one library, to standard output (console).

Thus, in case of the example input given above, the output of your program should be:

```
Mail Server
Video Call Server
```

because Mail Server is using older versions of the Authentication Library and the Data Storage Library, and Video Call Server is using an older version of the Authentication Library. Please read the example carefully to understand exactly what you're expected to do.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

```
string[] arr;
int version;
Dictionary<string, int> dctMax = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string item in inputLines)
{
    arr = item.Split(',');
    version = int.Parse(arr[2].Replace("v", ""));
    KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp = dctMax.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key.Equals(arr[1]));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key))
    {
        dctMax.Add(arr[1], version);
    }
    else
    {
        if (kvp.Value < version)
        {
            dctMax[kvp.Key] = version;
        }
    }
}

foreach (string item in inputLines)
{
    arr = item.Split(',');
    version = int.Parse(arr[2].Replace("v", ""));
    dctMax.TryGetValue(arr[1], out int maxVal);
    if (version < maxVal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item + " is old. Latest version is : " + maxVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or maybe, creating an object including ServerName, LibraryName, Version properties is more elegant.